# Name jdbc is not bound in this Context in Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc

I'm having trouble with JDBC Connection Pooling, I've done all the same with explained here: [JNDI Resources HOW-TO](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html), and here is also [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6468109/javax-naming-namenotfoundexception-name-jdbc-is-not-bound-in-this-context) (the same configuration with mine) regarding this topic which has not been resolved, I think.
What else should I consider?

Comment: Please post the server.xml. context file and the stacktrace.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I hope you have done the [ResourceLink](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html#Resource%20Links) configuration to your webapp, too.

```xml
<Context>
  ...
  <ResourceLink global="jdbc/MyDS" name="jdbc/MyDS" type="javax.sql.DataSource" />
  ...
</Context>
```

Comment: Thank you, yes I had done it as well... besides that in my conf/server.xml I put additional <Resource /> with attributes

Answer (score 3):

I had this error when the **JDBC driver was deleted from classpath**. In my setup, Tomcat expected libraries in a special directory, which was filled by Maven executing a special target. Whenever I cleaned and forgot to execute the Maven's target prior to running Tomcat, I had precisely this error.