# Tomcat 8.5 - Can't access mysql JDBC resource in contextInitialized method of ServletContextListener

Tags: java, jdbc, initialization, connection-pool, tomcat8.5

My web application has a servlet listener like this:

```
@WebListener
public class MyContextListener implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent e)
    {
        ...
        con = DatasourceProvider.getDatasource("java:comp/env/jdbc/mysql/mydb").getConnection();
        ...
    }
}
```

My resource definition is OK & it has worked fine it tomcat 7, but when I upgraded to tomcat server 8.5, it throws an exception at startup:

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc/mysql/mydb] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc].
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:816)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:159)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:827)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:159)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:827)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:173)
    at org.apache.naming.SelectorContext.lookup(SelectorContext.java:163)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
    ...
```

Anyway, I can get mysql connections after server starup (in the other servlets) using same code without any problem. So the question is that what causes this error while tomcat startup?

**UPDATE**
Here is my virtual host configuration:

```
<Host name="my-domain.ir" appBase="/var/www/webapp" >
    <Context path="" docBase="MyWebApp" 
     xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false" crossContext="false" reloadable="false" >
    <Resource name="jdbc/mysql/mydb" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"

    initialSize="1" maxTotal="100" maxIdle="2"
    maxWaitMillis="20000" removeAbandonedOnMaintenance="true" removeAbandonedTimeout="300"
    validationQuery="select now();"

    username="myUser" password="myPass" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8&amp;characterSetResults=UTF-8&amp;connectionCollation=UTF8_PERSIAN_CI&amp;noAccessToProcedureBodies=true"
    />
    </Context>
</Host>
```

Comment: Can you share your `context.xml`?

Comment: @N00bPr0grammer it's default `context.xml` for tomcat 8.5 & I haven't changed it. But if you mean `Context` element of my web application, I added it to the update

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue as like you, for which I added the a line (similar to this) into my Tomcat's `context.xml` to resolve the issue.

```
<ResourceLink global="jdbc/mysql/mydb" name="jdbc/mysql" type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
```

Following are the links to questions that point out to a similar solution

[Question-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22545169/name-jdbc-mydb-is-not-bound-in-this-context)

[Question-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6468109/javax-naming-namenotfoundexception-name-jdbc-is-not-bound-in-this-context)

[Question-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16737754/javax-naming-namenotfoundexception-name-is-not-bound-in-this-context-unable-to)

Hope that helps!!!

Comment: But I can't do this because I've too many virtual hosts & each one has it's own resources & I don't want & can't make them global. In addition, there should be a rational reason for this situation.

Comment: Now that's interesting, let me see what I can do on this then!